# out of sample definition

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, forecasting, computational-finance

Can anyone explain the difference between “in-sample” and “out-of-sample” forecasts?

Comment: What, specifically, are you talking about? Are you talking about data points that lie outside of the sampling distribution mean?

Answer (score 11):

It is statistics speak which in most cases means "using past data to make forecasts of the future".   "In sample" refers to the data that you have, and "out of sample" to the data you don't have but want to forecast or estimate.

Answer (score 7):

The data points used to build the model constitute *in sample data* where as all the new data points not belonging to the training sample constitute *out of sample data*.